# How to open an application from another application in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, actionview

How can I launch an application from my app. For eg:if there is link in my app and when I click on that link it should open another app.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
private void playVideo(){
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + videoId)));
    lastMonoSrc=5;
}
```